# Is Gogeta super saiyan blue confirmed in the new Dragon Ball Super movie?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, japanese-language, dragon-ball-movies

There are many people talking about not only that they think Gogeta will appear in the new movie, but they are refering to a supposed tweet where a japanese animator said he's going to do Gogeta in the new movie. Does anyone know if this official? Supposedly the official release of this info was done in japanese. Any translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gogeta Blue hasn't been "**confirmed**" to appear in the DBS movie. However, it seems very likely that it might be the case. An animator *Yoshihiko  Umakoshi*, mentioned on a live NikoNiko broadcast that he was practicing Gogeta. While the above mentioned information is accurate, it has to be noted that Umakoshi's names isn't on the film credits. However, not all the animators working for the Dragon Ball Super movie have been named.

When the new DLC (Extra Pack 3), was released for Xenoverse 2, on further Datamining, there was one character who had *Super Mad Dance* as a super and the *Vanisher Guard* evasive which are Gogeta's moves. Another character had the *Gigantic Meteor* Ultimate who is implied to be Broly. Hence, Gogeta Blue and Broly are being predicted to be the new characters that get released in Extra Pack 4, after the movie.

Further information with regard to the animator and his comments can be read [here](https://comicbook.com/anime/2018/09/13/dragon-ball-super-anime-gogeta-movie-appearance/).

Answer (score 0):

No. Gogeta is not confirmed for the movie and likely will not be in the movie. There is a Datamine for Xenoverse 2 that implies there will be a new Gogeta and Broly character in the game but that's just it. It's only a video game. Dragon Ball Heroes has shown us SSJ4 Vegito. And other Dragon Ball Video Games have shown us SSJ4 Gohan, SSJ3 Broly, SSJ4 Broly etc. So using a Video Game to prove something is not always a good idea. And in September, there was an Animator, named Yoshihiko Umakoshi, who was interviewed on NicoNico. But that is actually all we know for 100% certainty. This interview aired live and was never recorded, so we have no way of going back to watch it to see what was said. The person who claimed Yoshihiko said he was drawing Gogeta for Dragon Ball (Note: The person claimed Yoshihiko said Dragon Ball, not Dragon Ball Super, there is a difference), is just a random person in Japan who is also a fan of Dragon Ball. It wasn't Yoshihiko himself who went on Twitter or anyone related to Dragon Ball Super/Toei Animation in any Official Capacity. Just a random Average Joe fan like the rest of us.

Comment: It has now been confirmed :)